# GitLab OpenID id_token missing user profile claims

Tags: oauth, gitlab, openid, claims

I am trying to use GitLab (Self Hosted CE Edition) as OpenID Auth Provider. I am following https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/openid_connect_provider.html#enabling-openid-connect-for-oauth-applications and https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/oauth2.html#gitlab-as-an-oauth2-provider to verify the flow manually.

I have created the GitLab App to generate Client ID & secret. I can also get the Authorization Code Successfully by hitting `https://gitlab.example.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&response_type=code&state=YOUR_UNIQUE_STATE_HASH&scope=openid`

I am also able to retrieve id_token(JWT) by calling POST on `https://gitlab.example.com/oauth/token?client_id=ID&client_secret=SECRET&code=CODE&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http://localhost`

But when I decode the `id_token` on jwt.io, I am not able to see all the user profile claims mentioned on the docs link. following is the example JWT Payload I get

```
{
  "iss": "https://gitlab.example.com",
  "sub": "768d4eeae122ca6655c9127487d9c4cd85b079796d35d33753b3c15b93486044",
  "aud": "c3be56f955c74f0601683654df61ed3f74774902e2fb6da7ce05415b8a30e1d7",
  "exp": 1521463699,
  "iat": 1521463579,
  "auth_time": 1521456265
}
```

Can anyone please help on how I can get various user profile attributes in the `claims` like email, name etc.?

I am using GitLab Community Edition 10.5.0 34d5766

Comment: You can use the API to fetch the user details instead. It's not a good practice to put everything in claims. You can find the API reference for fetching user details [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/users.html).

Comment: My use case requires that I at least have email and email_verified claims in token.

Answer (score 0):

This use case would no longer apply with [GitLab 16.4](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/09/22/gitlab-16-4-released/#set-idtoken-globally-and-eliminate-configuration-for-individual-jobs) (September 2023):

> ### Set id_token globally and eliminate configuration for individual jobs
>
> In GitLab 15.9 we announced the [deprecation of older versions of JSON web tokens](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/deprecations.html?removal_milestone=17.0#old-versions-of-json-web-tokens-are-deprecated) in favor of `id_token`.
>
> Unfortunately, jobs had to be modified individually to accommodate this change.
>
> To enable a smooth transition to `id_token`, beginning from GitLab 16.4, you can set `id_tokens` as a global default value in `.gitlab-ci.yml`.
> This feature automatically sets the `id_token` configuration for every job.
> Jobs that use OpenID Connect (OIDC) authentication no longer require you to set up a separate `id_token`.
>
> [Use `id_token` and OIDC to authenticate with third party services](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/secrets/id_token_authentication.html).
> The required `aud` sub-keyword is used to configure the `aud` claim for the JWT.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/16_4/id_tokens_img.png -- Set id_token globally and eliminate configuration for individual jobs]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#id_tokens) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/419750).